# error in PHP code for email validation

Tags: php, mysql, database, email, validation

I am trying to create an email validation form for my database but am having a number of issues. When i try and run the code below i get the error no database selected.

I also get an undefined variable error. I want the put the name of the user into my database under the username field, but apparently $name is an undefined variable. error on line xx undefined variable`mysql_query("INSERT INTO registrations (username, password, email, hash) VALUES( '". mysql_real_escape_string($name) ."',`.

I am using WAMP server. The name of the database is sitememberdetails, and the name of the 
table i need the information put into is registrations. I am pretty new to this - Could anyone tell me how i would define the variable and how i select the db( even though it already appears to be selected?)

```
     <?php

             $host = "localhost";
             $username = "";
             $password = "";
             $databasename = "sitememberdetails";
             $email="xxxxxx@xxxxxxxx.xxx";


              $connection = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die        
             ("Error: ".mysql_error());

               mysql_select_db($databasename);("sitememberdetails") or  

               die(mysql_error());   



                    if(isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name']) AND  

                    isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email'])){  
                     $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);  
                     $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']); }  



                      if(!preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a- 

                        z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", $email)){

$msg = 'The email you have entered is invalid, please try again.';  
                }else{  

                    $msg = 'Your account has been made, <br /> please verify it     

              by clicking the activation link that has been send to  

                 your email.';  
                       }  


                        $hash = md5( rand(0,1000) ); 


                         $password = rand(1000,5000); 



                        mysql_query("INSERT INTO registrations (username, password,  

                          email, hash) VALUES( 
                          '". mysql_real_escape_string($name) ."', 
                          '". mysql_real_escape_string(md5($password)) ."', 
                          '". mysql_real_escape_string($email) ."', 
                          '". mysql_real_escape_string($hash) ."') ") or  

                          die(mysql_error());



                             $to      = $email; // Send email to our user  
                      $subject = 'Signup | Verification'; // Give the email a subject  
                      $message = ' 
                       Thanks for signing up! 
                      Your account has been created, you can login with the following  

                       credentials after you have activated your account by pressing  

                       the url below. 

                 Username: '.$name.' 
                 Password: '.$password.' 

                      Please click this link to activate your account: 
                      http://www.yourwebsite.com/verify.php?email='.$email.'& 

                      hash='.$hash.' 
                       ';  
                     $headers = 'From:noreply@yourwebsite.com' . "\r\n"; // Set from  

                       headers  
                       mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); // Send our email  


                        ?>
```

Comment: Please look into using [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead of the old mysql driver. The mysql driver is now unsupported and has some security issues.

Comment: You should avoid using mysql_* functions as they are depreciated.

Comment: Use `filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` instead of regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing this code

```
mysql_select_db($databasename);("sitememberdetails") or  

           die(mysql_error());
```

to this

```
mysql_select_db($databasename) or  die(mysql_error());
```

EOL;

```
if (database_connection) {
unset($undefined_variable_error)
} else {
echo $undefined_variable_error;
}
// Because mysql_real_escape_string needs an open mysql connection
```

Comment: Thanks Delta that solved the problem. Except i now have another 1! Fixing this error means a database is now selected, but now it says "Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'sitememberdetails'"!! The database names are correct, shouldnt i be allowed access if the username and password are left blank? I havnt changed them in phpmyadmin.

Comment: i think wamp servers default mysql username is root. but i am not sure, because i am not using it. here is an google search result for this http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090716053359AAx59vM

Comment: Last question i promise - specified the username as root and now it states " Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at &quot;localhost&quot; port 25, verify your &quot;SMTP&quot; and &quot;smtp_port&quot; setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\wamp\www\Root\siginuppage.php on line 90". This is the "mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);". It's like the more problems are solved the more emerge! Is this something to do with the fact that the site isint live at the moment?

Comment: you have to set up a smtp server on your machine or try this code on a real server. nearly all hosting companies set up smtp server on their web servers.

Answer (score 1):

check out this modified code:

```
<?php
         $host = "localhost";
         $username = "";
         $password = "";
         $databasename = "sitememberdetails";
         $email="xxxxxx@xxxxxxxx.xxx";


        $connection = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db($databasename) or die(mysql_error());   


               $name = "";
           if(isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name']) AND  
           isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email'])){  
                 $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);  
                 $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']); }  



                if(!preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", $email)){
                    $msg = 'The email you have entered is invalid, please try again.';  }
            else { 
                $msg = 'Your account has been made, <br /> please verify it     
                            by clicking the activation link that has been send to your email.';  
                  }  


            $hash = md5( rand(0,1000) ); 
            $password = rand(1000,5000); 

            mysql_query("INSERT INTO registrations (username, password,email, hash) VALUES( 
                      '". mysql_real_escape_string($name) ."', 
                      '". mysql_real_escape_string(md5($password)) ."', 
                      '". mysql_real_escape_string($email) ."', 
                      '". mysql_real_escape_string($hash) ."') ") or die(mysql_error());

            $to = $email; // Send email to our user  
                $subject = 'Signup | Verification'; // Give the email a subject  
            $message = ' Thanks for signing up! 
                Your account has been created, you can login with the following  
                credentials after you have activated your account by pressing  
                the url below. 
                    Username: '.$name.' 
                    Password: '.$password.' 
                Please click this link to activate your account: 
                http://www.yourwebsite.com/verify.php?email='.$email.'& 
                hash='.$hash.' 
               ';  

            $headers = 'From:noreply@yourwebsite.com' . "\r\n"; // Set from  

                mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); // Send our email  

?>
```

and i advise you to use PDO instead of mysql_ functions

Comment: thnks Isa/dcirello - I am extremely new to this but hav a deadline, so im just going to try and get the code working anyway i can first, and once its up and running i will try and update the deprecated tags.      The code works fine, except i keep getting the error "Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'sitememberdetails'". Would you have any idea why this is the case? I am using Wampserver.

Comment: check the user and privileges in phpMyAdmin panel for that user you used in the connection. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the $name value isn't getting posted to the form.  You're mysql_escaping the name variable if it is set and isn't empty, but what happens if the name variable isn't set at all?  There are no checks for this so it continues until it gets to the INSERT statement and causes an error.

Look at example #1 [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php) to select the db.  You have a semicolon after ($databasename); which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some revised code, using PDO instead of mysql_*. Let me know if this one works and we can address any issues from there.

```
<?php

            $host = 'localhost';
            $dbname = 'sitememberdetails';
            $user = '';
            $pass = '';
            try
            {
                $DB = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass); 
            }
            catch(PDOException $e)
            {  
                echo $e->getMessage();  
            }

            if(isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name']) AND isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email']))
            {  
                $name = $_POST['name'];  
                $email = $_POST['email'];
            }
            else
            {
                $name = 'No Name';  
                $email = 'No Email';
            }

            if(!preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", $email))
            {
                $msg = 'The email you have entered is invalid, please try again.';  
            }else{  
                $msg = 'Your account has been made, <br /> please verify it by clicking the activation link that has been send to your email.';  
            }  

            $hash = md5( rand(0,1000) ); 
            $password = rand(1000,5000); 

            $query = "INSERT INTO registrations (username, password, email, hash) VALUES('?', '?', '?', '?')";
            $sth = $DB->prepare($query);
            //By using ?'s and prepare/execute, PDO will prevent SQL Injection for you!
            $sth->execute(array($name, md5($password), $email, $hash));

            $to      = $email; // Send email to our user  
            $subject = 'Signup | Verification'; // Give the email a subject  
            $message = 'Thanks for signing up! Your account has been created, 
                        you can login with the following credentials after you 
                        have activated your account by pressing the url below. 
                        Username: '.$name.' 
                        Password: '.$password.' 

                        Please click this link to activate your account: 
                        http://www.yourwebsite.com/verify.php?email='.$email.'& 

                        hash='.$hash;  
            $headers = 'From:noreply@yourwebsite.com' . "\r\n"; // Set from header  
            mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); // Send our email  
?>
```

Comment: Cheers Sam - I'm getting two errors both on line :  "$sth = $DB->prepare($query); ".   The errors are "Undefined variable: DB in C:\wamp\www\Root\siginuppage.php" & " Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\Root\siginuppage.php ".

Comment: @Danielokeeffe I would expect this to be an issue regarding Database connection. try putting $DB = "1"; below the echo in the catch statement and see if that 'removes' the first error, if so, then it means that your initial database connection is failing.